# My redirect function is not working in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following code:

```
$this->video->videoupdate($userid, $title, $id);
redirect("admin/videos", "refresh");
```

But the redirect is not working and I don't know why (I am using CodeIgniter)

Comment: What is `$this->video->videoupdate()`?

Comment: what do you mean by "is not working", what is it doing? also the more code you give the better, let us see `videoupdate`

Comment: I am just updating values in the database.. its codeignitor.if i give script redirect it works

Comment: what do you mean by 'script redirect'?

Comment: if the message you get is something like 'headers allready sent' you should follow kevintrout's advice and move your redirect before view loaders...and your question is not good at all you should explain what's happening with more detail(errors, warnings etc..)if you hope  getting a good answer...Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Have you sent anything to the browser prior to calling redirect?  From the user guide

> Note: In order for this function to
>   work it must be used before anything
>   is outputted to the browser since it
>   utilizes server headers.

Answer (score 0):

have you loaded the URL helper?

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Load this in your controller. I usually put mine either in the constructor or the autoload config.

Comment: try redirect('/'); this should redirect you to your base url. if it works it'll confirm redirect is working

Comment: Also, maybe try your code using single quotes and without the second parameter

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
redirect("admin/videos");
```

without "refresh"

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the echo if any above redirect
2. Check your htaccess, write like this:

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|robots\.txt)
   RewriteBase /sitename/
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d``
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I have just fixed it with this ->

$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:3000/';

So apparently you must define this before use your url helper.

Comment: please format code as code by adding a 4-space indentation to it