# I want to know what's happening in this script?? What is the difference?

Tags: php, codeigniter

In CodeIgniter

```
 $confirm=$this->video->videoupdate(any values);// Here i am just updating my database
 if($confirm)
 echo "<script>window.location='index';</script>";


 $this->video->videoupdate(any values);// Here i am just updating my database
 echo "<script>window.location='index';</script>";
```

Can u explain me detail guys...

is it compulsory  to check this condition?

Comment: This question appears to be a repost/minor modification of this question, in case it helps provide an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817482/my-redirect-function-is-not-working-in-codeignitor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first case script redirect if the record is successfully updated.

in second case does not matter what happen with the record it will always redirect.

Answer (score 6):

In the first example you are setting a variable `$confirm` which (I assume) will either be `true` or `false` based on whether the update succeeds and then redirecting if it does. In the second example you are redirecting regardless of whether the update succeeds or not.

Comment: oh k .$this->video->videoupdate(any values);// Here i am just updating my database
 echo "<script>window.location='index';</script>"; i think php should go to redirect statement after completion of update right.

Answer (score 0):

```
// example 1
$confirm=$this->video->videoupdate('any values');
if($confirm)
{
    echo "window.location='index';";
}

// example 2
$this->video->videoupdate('any values');
echo "window.location='index';";
```

Your `videoupdate` method will return a value. Generally you return `true` or `false`, but can also return data. In example one you are assigning the result of the statement to `$confirm`.

if `$confirm` is `true` then the condition will be executed. Note that unless $confirm is explicitly set to `false`, any value will evaluate to `true`, so the condition will always be true.

A better option would be to do:

```
if($confirm==true) 
{ 
    // redirect
}
else
{
   // something else has happened
}
```

This logic can be used to control the flow of an application in the result of an error, for instance, or the failure of a query.

In the second example, the `echo` statement will occur regardless of outcome, which may be intended, but could result in unexpected behaviour - was the query successful or not at that point in the script.

Comment: hi ross,my problem here is before calling videoupdate().I am using ffmepg to convert to flv video.after converting the file name is stored in database by calling videoupdate ..after that my redirect should work(i.e after completly video is converted then it should update to my database then only it should redirect)